Elementor is loading widgets dynamically and causing massive CLS
I have a standard Elementor page layout with a header and a footer.  The main page content is generated by a custom shortcode in an Elementor Shortcode widget.  Unfortunately what Elementor seems to be doing is loading the header and footer first, then somehow injecting the page content afterwards.  When the content body loads it pushes the footer down by several thousand px, causing a terrible CLS score on Pagespeed.
The page content is generated in php not js, so I'm just not sure how it could be injected dynamically, but that is exactly what is happening - I can throttle the connection and load the page in slow motion and I can see the page is first rendered with
<div class="elementor-widget-wrap"></div>

where the content should be.  Later the content get injected and the elementor-element-populated is added to the wrapper:
<div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
   ---- content html ---
</div>

How do I fix the CLS issue here?  Is there a way to render the page content after the header and before the footer?
